# Pandas MAX formula across different grouped rows

Tags: pandas

I have dataframe that looks like this:

```
Auction_id  bid_price  min_bid  rank
123         5          3        1
123         4          3        2
124         3          2        1
124         1          2        2
```

I'd like to create another column that returns MAX(rank 1 min_bid, rank 2 bid_price). I don't care what appears for the rank 2 column values. I'm hoping for the result to look something like this:

```
Auction_id  bid_price  min_bid  rank  custom_column
123         5          3        1     4
123         4          3        2     NaN/Don't care
124         3          2        1     2
124         1          2        2     NaN/Don't care
```

Should I be iterating through grouped auction_ids? Can someone provide the topics one would need to be familiar with to tackle this type of problem?

Comment: Are there only two rows per Auction id?  And the rank is always 1 or 2?

Comment: Yes - I will eventually purge the rank 2 rows as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, set the index equal to the `Auction_id`.  Then you can use `loc` to select the appropriate values for each `Auction_id` and use max on their values.  Finally, reset your index to return to your initial state.

```
df.set_index('Auction_id', inplace=True)
df['custom_column'] = pd.concat([df.loc[df['rank'] == 1, 'min_bid'],
                                 df.loc[df['rank'] == 2, 'bid_price']],
                                axis=1).max(axis=1)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
>>> df
   Auction_id  bid_price  min_bid  rank  custom_column
0         123          5        3     1              4
1         123          4        3     2              4
2         124          3        2     1              2
3         124          1        2     2              2
```

Comment: This method is especially useful when dealing with larger data sets (I'm getting memory errors using functions). 

One additional question - is it possible to on run the concatenation if the rank2 bid price is less than the rank 1 bid price? If rank2 bid_price > rank1 bid_price, I want to return the rank1 min_bid.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one crude way to do it.

Create `maxminbid()` function, which creates a `val=` MAX(rank 1 min_bid, rank 2 bid_price) and assign this to `grp['custom_column']`, and for `rank==2` store it with `NaN`

```
def maxminbid(grp):
    val = max(grp.loc[grp['rank']==1, 'min_bid'].values,
              grp.loc[grp['rank']==2, 'bid_price'].values)[0]
    grp['custom_column'] = val
    grp.loc[grp['rank']==2, 'custom_column'] = pd.np.nan
    return grp
```

Then apply `maxminbid` function on `Auction_id` grouped objects

```
df.groupby('Auction_id').apply(maxminbid)


   Auction_id  bid_price  min_bid  rank  custom_column
0         123          5        3     1              4
1         123          4        3     2            NaN
2         124          3        2     1              2
3         124          1        2     2            NaN
```

But, I suspect, there must be some elegant solution than this one.

Comment: I don't think it's crude at all.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that does some reshaping with pivot()

```
   Auction_id  bid_price  min_bid  rank  
0         123          5        3     1              
1         123          4        3     2           
2         124          3        2     1            
3         124          1        2     2
```

Then reshape your frame (df)

```
pv = df.pivot("Auction_id","rank")
pv
                   bid_price    min_bid   
rank               1    2       1  2
Auction_id                        
123                5    4       3  3
124                3    1       2  2
```

Adding a column to pv that contains the max. I"m using iloc to get a slice of the  pv dataframe.

```
    pv["custom_column"]  = pv.iloc[:,[1,2]].max(axis=1)
    pv

                 bid_price    min_bid    custom_column
rank               1  2       1  2              
Auction_id                                      
123                5  4       3  3             4
124                3  1       2  2             2
```

and then add the max to the original frame (df) by mapping to our pv frame

```
df.loc[df["rank"] == 1,"custom_column"] = df["Auction_id"].map(pv["custom_column"])
df

  Auction_id  bid_price  min_bid  rank  custom_column
0         123          5        3     1              4
1         123          4        3     2            NaN
2         124          3        2     1              2
3         124          1        2     2            NaN
```

all the steps combined

```
pv = df.pivot("Auction_id","rank")
pv["custom_column"] = pv.iloc[:,[1,2]].max(axis=1)
df.loc[df["rank"] == 1,"custom_column"] = df["Auction_id"].map(pv["custom_column"])
df

  Auction_id  bid_price  min_bid  rank  custom_column
0         123          5        3     1              4
1         123          4        3     2            NaN
2         124          3        2     1              2
3         124          1        2     2            NaN
```